# What is the purpose of _grecaptcha in Local Storage?

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-enterprise

When calling Google reCAPTCHA API-related interfaces on a frontend page, a key named _grecaptcha is written to Local Storage. Although the documentation describes it as being used to record some configurations and ensure data security, I still want to know the specific configurations used and how account security is ensured.

Is it possible to make API calls to Google reCAPTCHA on a frontend page without writing the _grecaptcha key to Local Storage?

Is it possible to make API calls to Google reCAPTCHA on a frontend page without writing the _grecaptcha key to Local Storage?

Comment: `_grecaptcha is a functional cookie used by Google recaptcha. It's used for risk analysis in spam protection and may store browsing device information.` https://www.iubenda.com/en/help/23902-google-recaptcha-gdpr-how-to-be-compliant

Answer (score 0):

From the [reCAPTCHA docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#does-recaptcha-use-cookies)

> reCAPTCHA sets a necessary cookie (_GRECAPTCHA) when executed for the purpose of providing its risk analysis. If you prefer to not use the [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) domain which may have other cookies set, you can use [www.recaptcha.net](http://www.recaptcha.net) instead.

This cookie is necessary for reCAPTCHA to make an assessment if the traffic to the site is legitimate or malicious. The `grecaptcha.enterprise.execute` function will use these signals to generate an obfuscated token, which you can send to the reCAPTCHA API for an evaluation if this traffic should be permitted. The exact signals that are evaluated are not publicly available as doing so would assist in evasion methods.